# Vertically align twitter bootstrap thumbnails?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

**Update:** Plnkr available here to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/i6ngfaMgSE0XGZq3VuBW?p=preview (although you need to widen the "preview" window so that the responsive stuff doesn't kick in.

So I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap's `thumbnails` and `thumbnail` classes to produce an image-gallery type effect, however I'm having trouble trying to get the images to all align properly.

All the thumbnails being retrieved from the server are scaled uniformly so that they fit in a 200px X 200px image. However, sometimes they are much wider than tall (200px X 100px) and vice-versa (100px X 200px). What I want is to have all my images vertically and horizontally centred within the row they are on. So for example in this:

[image]

I'd like `testImage`, `testImage2` and `testImage3` to be moved down in their containers so that the  tags all lined up.

Here's the HTML (with some AngularJS bindings):

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="StaticDataManagementCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <tabset>
        <tab heading="Text" select="loadTextLibrary()">
          <div class="row"></div>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Images" select="loadImageLibrary()">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
              <li class="span3" ng-repeat="image in staticImages">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img ng-src="/api/static/images/{{image._id}}/thumb">
                  <h3>{{image.name}}</h3>
                  <p>Some sample description</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Health Mark" select="loadHealthMarkLibrary()"></tab>
      </tabset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-properly-align-an-image-vertically

Answer (score 1):

Try to do with following css:

```
.thumbnail{
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

Comment: Is the `!important` necessary here?

Comment: No but if you give !important then it override other css and make this css as important.

Comment: I've already tried this to no avail. I'll try to setup a Plunkr to demonstrate, for easier editing / testing.

Comment: Okay, added the Plnkr to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14961550/187009) should help. Basically you have to fix the `height` of the text and images. Bootstrap has an `.img-responsive` that will help with scaling, and don't forget `overflow:hidden`.